# Regex: match words, omit newline

Tags: regex, xml, r

I'm new to regex (and stackoverflow btw) and trying to extract "real" words out of this using R:

```
"\n\n\nclone\nstar\n\n\n\n\nbrain\nstar\n\n\n\n\ncalculator\nstar\n\n\n\n\nadding machine\nstar\n\n\n\n\nartificial intelligence\nstar"
```

So i would like to match: clone, brain, calculator, adding machine, artificial intelligence.

I tried it with `(?<=\\n)(.*?)(?=\\nstar)` which seems to be close...but it still doesn't give me what I want. I guess I don't have to specify \n but instead use some omit newline comment?

Comment: Try `gsub('\n', ' ', str1)`  You could have showed the expected output

Comment: What output are you expecting?

Comment: are your `\n` real newlines or a literal backslashes followed by a `n`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(?<=\\n)((?:(?!\\n).)*?)(?=\\nstar)
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/vD5iH9/63

`.*?` will capture everything including `\n`.So use a `lookahead` to check if `\n` is not being captured.

Comment: Possible, I asked him the question.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte i guessed so from the regex OP used.

Comment: you guessed right! This was exactly what I needed. Regex can be quite confusing at the beginning...especially in R. So thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to pull out the words?

```
strsplit(x,'\n+')
```

or match them?

```
gsub('[a-zA-Z]+','HELLOWORLD',x)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a vector of words

```
x <- "\n\n\nclone\nstar\n\n\n\n\nbrain\nstar\n\n\n\n\ncalculator\nstar\n\n\n\n\nadding machine\nstar\n\n\n\n\nartificial intelligence\nstar"
x <- gsub("\n"," ",x)
x <- unlist(strsplit(x," "))
x <- x[x != ""]
```

Answer (score 0):

This does it with a relatively simple regular expression:

```
library(gsubfn)

strapplyc(x, "([^\n]*).star", simplify = c)
```

giving:

```
[1] "clone"  "brain"  "calculator"  "adding machine"         
[5] "artificial intelligence"
```

**Note:** Here is a visualization of the regular expression:

```
([^\n]*).star
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/7neqVhUqeaG6tZQw)

Answer (score 0):

Just split on \nstar or \n and optionally remove leading characters to avoid the empty first string.

```
strsplit(x, "(\nstar|\n)+")   # OR
strsplit(gsub("^\n*", "", x), "(\n|star)+")[[1]]
[1] "clone"                   "brain"                   "calculator"             
[4] "adding machine"          "artificial intelligence"
```